# Como somar a coluna de uma tabela em PHP

Tags: php, operadores

Boa noite pessoal,
 Eu trago em uma tabela um resultado de um `select` de um banco,porém  no resultado:

> echo"".$T_TOTAL."";

Estou trazendo de uma variável pois tive que fazer um tratamento para chegar a meu resultado.

> Duvida: Como consigo somar o resultado da variável?

```
<?php
    echo"<table class='datatable table table-hover table-bordered table-responsiv'>";
    echo"<thead>";
    echo"<tr>";
    echo"<th>CELULAR</th>";
    echo"<th>DESCRIÇÃO</th>";
    echo"<th>TEMPO</th>";
    echo"<th>VALOR</th>";
    echo"</tr>";
    echo"</thead>";
    echo"<tbody>";       
    echo"<tr>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_pesquisa)) {
    $TEMPO=$row['VALOR'];
    $T_TOTAL=$TEMPO / 6 * 0.015 ;
    echo"<td>".$row['CELULAR']."</td>";
    echo"<td>".$row['DESCRICAO']."</td>";
    echo"<td>".$row['MINUTOS']."</td>";
    echo"<td>".$T_TOTAL."</td>";
    echo"</tr>";
      } 
   echo" </tbody>";
   echo" </table>";   

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inicie a variável com valor zero.

Dentro do laço de repetição, incremente o valor de cada soma.

Apenas não confunda o subtotal (total unitário) com o total geral.

Observe que foi criado mais row `<tr></tr>` depois do laço, para exibir o total geral.

Não sei ao certo se é esse o resultado que pretende. Apenas me orientei pela dedução mais lógica.

```
$T_TOTAL = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_pesquisa)) {
;
$subotal =$row['VALOR'] / 0.09; // 6 * 0.015
$T_TOTAL += $subotal;
echo "<td>".$row['CELULAR']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['DESCRICAO']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['MINUTOS']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$subotal."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "<tr><td colspan="3" style="text-align:right;">total: </td><td>".$T_TOTAL."</td></tr>";
```

Na parte de cálculo do subtotal, modifiquei  expressão `6 * 0.015` por `0.09` porque se a expressão será sempre a mesma, é redundante fazer o PHP calcular sempre o mesmo valor. É mais performático (executa mais rápido) se colocar o valor já calculado.

Comment: Boa tarde,Mais eu preciso desse calculo (6 * 0.015),se eu deixar ele não da certo ?

Comment: Foi apenas uma sugestão pois se essa expressão for fixa, então sugeri já deixar o valor calculado. Por isso, 6 multiplicado por `0.015` resulta `0.09`. Mas se quiser pode deixar como `6 * 0.015`. Claro que é um ganho de performance ridículo, mas de qualquer forma é uma lógica para otimização. Quanto menos processos para chegar a um mesmo resultado e, de forma eficiente, melhor.

Comment: Hum entendi,obrigado por detalhar e é exatamente o que eu precisava,Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

### Introdução aos operadores no PHP

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Um operador é utilizado para realizar operações entre um ou mais valores (ou expressões, no jargão de programação) e retornar apenas um valor final. Vamos agora aos operadores.

**Operadores aritméticos no PHP**

```
<?php
// Declarando os valores das variáveis
$a = 4;
$b = 2;

?>
<h2>Adição</h2>
<p>
<?php

echo $a + $b;

?>
</p>
<h2>Subtração</h2>
<p>
<?php

echo $a - $b;

?>
</p>
<h2>Multiplicação</h2>
<p>
<?php

echo $a * $b;

?>
</p>
<h2>Divisão</h2>
<p>
<?php

echo $a / $b;

?>
</p>
<h2>Módulo(resto da divisão)</h2>
<p>
<?php

echo $a % $b;

?>
</p>
```